# Why do certain inner-product conditions imply linear independence?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $x_1,\ldots,x_k, y_1,\ldots,y_k\in\mathbb R^n=\mathbb R^{1\times n}$ be $2k$ vectors such that
>   $x_iy_i^T=0, \forall i=1,\ldots,k$
>   $x_iy_j^T=1, \forall 1\le i\lt j\le k.$
>   Then the vectors $x_i$ are linearly independent, and so are the vectors $y_i.$ Conclude that $k\le n.$

Write $A=\begin{bmatrix}x_1^T,\ldots,x_k^T\end{bmatrix}^T, B=\begin{bmatrix}y_1^T,\ldots,y_k^T\end{bmatrix}^T\in\operatorname{M}_{k\times n}(\mathbb R).$ Then the condition means that $AB^T$ is a $k\times k$ matrix whose diagonals $=0,$ and whose upper triangular entries are $=1.$ But the problem is: I do not see how this implies the linear independence of the original vectors $x_i$ and $y_i.$
I supposed that $\sum_i a_ix_i=0$ for some $a_i\in\mathbb R.$ Then, forming the inner-product with the $y_j$ ... gives us nothing: there are too many unknown coefficients in $AB^T!$
Thanks in advance for any hints or references.

Comment: I think you have an error. You have to change to $x_iy_i^T=1, \forall i=1,\ldots,k$ and $x_iy_j^T=0, \forall 1\le i\lt j\le k$.

Comment: This comes from a pre-retired exam, and I copied it almost verbatim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it is not true as stated:

Here is a counterexample in $\mathbb{R}^3$:
Take $x_k = e_k^T$, and let $y_1=(0, 1 , -1)$, $y_2 = (1,0,1)$ and $y_3 = (1,1,0)$.

Then $x_k y_k^T = 0$, and $x_1 y_2^T = 1$, $x_1 y_3^T = 1$, $x_2 y_3^T = 1$.

However $y_1+y_2 = y_3$, so they are not linearly independent.

Comment: Thanks for the ingenious counter-example! Indeed, with some modifications, this even contradicts the independence of $x_i.$

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by following hypotheses:

1.$x_iy_i^T=1, \forall i=1,\ldots,k$

2.$x_iy_j^T=0, \forall 1\le i\lt j\le k$

Let $a_1x_1+a_2x_2+\cdots+a_kx_k=0$. Then, one can see that $a_1x_1y^T_k+a_2x_2y^T_k+\cdots+a_kx_ky_k^T=0$. Since $x_iy_k^T=0, \forall i=1,\ldots,k-1$ and $x_ky_k^T=1$, we can conclude that $a_k=0$. By similar argument, we can show that $a_i=0$ for   $\forall i=1,\ldots,k$.

Comment: OK, you can start with $y_k$. IN next step you use $y_{k-1}$

Comment: It can't be true in general.

Comment: I think you swapped the 0 and 1 in your hypotheses?

Comment: exactly. I have seen this problem many years ago, and I am sure about 0 and 1.

Comment: Well, it doesn't match the OP's question...